# Python Beginner - How to generate a list and frequency from another list

Tags: python, list, frequency

Given:

```
[['x','a'], ['y','b'], ['z','a']]
```

I would like a list of the elements and a count frequency of the 2nd element:

```
[['x','a',2], ['y','b',1], ['z','a',2]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [['x','a'], ['y','b'], ['z','a']]
>>> freq = Counter(y for x, y in L)
>>> [[x, y, freq[y]] for x, y in L]
[['x', 'a', 2], ['y', 'b', 1], ['z', 'a', 2]]
```

Answer (score 5):

As usual, [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) comes to the rescue.

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
pairs = [['x','a'], ['y','b'], ['z','a']]
counts = Counter(b for a,b in pairs)
pairs_with_counts = [[a, b, counts[b]] for a,b in pairs]
```

Comment: I would recommend not using lowercase `l` as a variable name, it can be confused with `1`

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution using a dictionary instead:

```
mylist = [['x','a'], ['y','b'], ['z','a']]
d = {}
for (a, b) in mylist:
    try:
        d[b] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[b] = 1

mynewlist = [[a, b, d[b]] for (a, b) in mylist]
print(mynewlist)
```

Output is `[['x', 'a', 2], ['y', 'b', 1], ['z', 'a', 2]]`

Comment: `Counter` is a dictionary. It does all this behind the scenes, just a lot faster